# Complex Number Powers of Coprime Rational Powers

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

I'm trying to figure out $z^{p/q}$ where $p,q$ are coprime.

Suppose I want to find $z^{2/7}$ where $z=128$. I can rewrite $z=128e^{0}$

Now I know that the $z^{1/7}$ roots are $2e^{k2\pi i/7}$ for $k=0,...6$.

What if now I need to compute the power $2/7$? Is it simply $2e^{4k\pi i/7}$.

Comment: For noninteger $a$, we define $z^a := \exp(a \log z)$, but this quantity depends on a choice of branch cut of $\log$. The set of $n$th roots of a number $w$ do not depend on a branch cut, but the meaning of the expression $w^{1 / n}$ does.

Comment: @Travis So if I pick a cut along the positive $x$ axis, will my answer be correct? In which case, what happens to the first root. Because it's on the branch cut

Comment: If you choose the log function whose imaginary part $\arg$ takes values in $[0, 2 \pi)$, then $128^{1 / 7} = \exp\left(\frac{1}{7} \log 128\right) = \exp \left(\frac{1}{7} \cdot 7 \log 2\right) = \exp \log 2 = 2$.

Comment: In fact, if $x$ is positive real and $a$ is real, in absence of other context, we usually interpret $x^a$ as the usual real power.

Comment: @Travis but if I take $a$ irrational, there will be infinite powers? Also, I see you showed me $1$ root, but there should be $7$. Also for the power $2/7$, do I simply multiply the arguement by $2$?

Comment: If $a$ is irrational, different choices of branch cuts lead to infinitely many values for $z^a$.

Comment: I showed how to compute the expression $128^{1 / 7}$ for a particular choice of branch cut (which has a single value). This is *not* the same as giving the set of $n$th roots ($n$ an integer $>1$) of a complex number, which contains $n$ elements, though the value of expression $z^{1 / n}$ (for any choice of branch cut) will be one of those elements.

Comment: Again, using the definition (and the same branch cut as before),
$128^{2 / 7} = \exp\left(\frac{2}{7} \log 128\right) = 4$.

Comment: @Travis thanks a lot :)